# how to access projects in xampp through virtual host from network connected pc

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

I have created a virtual host in my apache server and updated the same in hosts file in /System32/drivers/etc folder. and i am able to access my project through virtual host from the same pc.

My problem is when i am trying to access my project using the virtual host from a pc connected through network, it is not working.

its working with ip address of the server.

Simply, when replacing ip address with virtual host, i am not able to reach my site from a network connected pc

Comment: Can you show your host file ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1    mysite.com